# Is there a stronger glue for plastic than superglue?

Tags: adhesive

I got myself a pair of edifier headphones that sound fantastic but break all the time. Its a piece of plastic in a high stress area, just around where the swivel hinge connects to the cupholders - why that component is made from plastic while everything else is metal... who knows but there it is.

It keeps snapping in half and I keep gluing it together with locally available superglue which is just 100% ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate. Each time it stays glued for like 2-3 months but eventually it breaks again.

I don't know what type of plastic it is, its black and very rigid, if I had to guess I'd say its probably polyethylene but I red that cyanoacrylate glues don't work on PE and its clearly having at least some effect so it must be something else, right?

Anyway, the plastic piece  just broke again today so this time I'm wondering if there is a better type of glue available for this?

Comment: I am not an adhesives engineer, so I can't say it's an answer, but a search for "low surface energy adhesive" might lead you to something useful.

Answer (score 4):

I have used solvent glues with success in the past, weld on , locktight ,scigrip are brands I use depending on the plastic. You would need to get the super glue residue off first. Since you have had problems and it has been repaired I might try locktight plastic bonding set it uses an activator and a bonder or glue. The solvent type actually melt the plastics and the fuse the pieces together.